# How do i iterate all ASCII to use them as variable?

Tags: bash, echo

I have a binary "crackme" which i want to try all ASCII characters as parameters, here's what i've done so far.

```
 #!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                   

for ((i=32;i<127;i++))
do
    c="\\$(printf %03o "$i")";
    echo $c;
    ./crackme $c;
done
```

The command executed is "./crackme \65" and obviously i'm trying to execute "./crackme A".

Comment: i've tried lot of thing like what you've flagged, the main problem is that i can't figure out how to store the ascii value in a variable, every post are about simply printing the ascii value

Comment: Using the top answer from the duplicate: `i=65; printf "\x$(printf %x "$i")"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not pretty, but this works:

```
for ((i=32;i<127;i++))
do
    printf -v c '\\x%x' "$i"
    ./crackme "$(echo -e $c)"
done
```

Comment: You should probably stick with printf all the way: `./crackme "$(printf "$c")"`

Answer (score 4):

For posterity, a couple of useful functions:

```
# 65 -> A
chr() { printf "\\x$(printf "%x" "$1")"; }
# A -> 65
ord() { printf "%d" "'$1"; }
```

The odd final parameter of the `ord` printf command is [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-printf):

> Arguments to **non-string format specifiers** are treated as C language constants, except that a leading plus or minus sign is allowed, and **if the leading character is a single or double quote, the value is the ASCII value of the following character**.

then

```
for ((i = 32; i < 127; i++)); do
    ./crackme "$(chr $i)"
done
```

Comment: I never understood why bash (or ksh) does not have those as built-ins, just about every other language has them.